# AngularJS view showing old data quickly before showing the new data when switching between views

Tags: angularjs

I have a single page angularJS / nodejs / express app. When first loading the app, it pulls data via API from database and displays in a table in the 'home' route. 5 minutes later, it updates the data by doing the API call again then `$scope.$apply()`.

After the update if I navigate away from the 'home' route to a different view within the app, then back again, you can see the old data for a fraction of a second then the new data pops into place again.

This will happen repeatedly as I navigate away and back to the route.

It seem like the browser is saving the old data, then updating it every time I go back.

Why is this happening and how can I make the `$scope.apply` changes permanent?

Comment: So what you want is to load all data at the same time not one after the other, right?

Comment: clean the scope which shows the old data before switching to new state

Comment: This mean you want keep the `updated data` after back to `home` state, right?

Comment: I am also facing the same issue.

Comment: @BanshiL.Dangi see my answer below. Might be the same issue, but maybe not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to load the data into an object in a factory, and update the data object in the factory instead of in the controller.  This keeps the data up to date when changing views.